# Run 'uninstallAll' gradle task before running application in Android Studio from build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Before running my application I would like to uninstall any instances on the device. Running the task `uninstallAll` manually does this perfectly.

How can I call this command from my `build.gradle` so that this occurs each time automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may need is to set [defaultTasks](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:default_tasks):

```
defaultTasks uninstallAll
```

or specify appropriate tasks [dependencies](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies):

```
runTaskName.dependsOn(uninstallAll)
```

Comment: Where should I place these in my `build.gradle`? Within any section?

Comment: Out of any section, *just in* `build.gradle` itself.

Comment: I'm getting the following errors respectively for each method: `Error:(1, 0) Could not find property 'uninstallAll' on project ':App'.` and `Error:(52, 0) Could not find property 'runTaskName' on project ':App'.`

Comment: Do you have task `uninstallAll` defined? Do you run it with gradle? When it comes to `runTaskName` it's not exact.. You should replace it with task name used to run the application..

Comment: Yes when I open the Gradle pane in AS, the task is listed un `:App > Tasks > install > uninstallAll`. When I run it from here manually it works fine.

Comment: Ah it needs to be `defaultTasks 'uninstallAll'` but this did not work.

Comment: Ok, so how you run the application?

Comment: `Shift+F10` as usuall. One solution is to edit the configuration and add `uninstallAll` to the Before Launch section, though this will not be tracked in git.

Comment: Is there any task invoked after running with Shift + F10?

Comment: It launches `assembleDebug` as usual.

Comment: Basically I meant `runTaskName` to be `assembleDebug`.

Comment: Cool thanks. I was getting confused because AS was showing it as an undefined symbol.